# How to upload CSV to wordpress custom table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

How to upload CSV data to wordpress custom table wp_sonali_data. Bellow is the code what I'm trying. But no luck please help

**Here is my custom table column**

```
id
brcode
brname
dist
```

**Here is my uploader**

```
   <form method="post" action="">
<p>Choose your CSV file</p><br />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>


<?php

    //Upload CSV File
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    global $wordpress,$wpdb;
        $datafile= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file=$upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileurl=$upload_dir['baseurl'].'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$file)){
            print_r('Failed to move uploaded file.');
            }
        $sql="
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$fileurl."' INTO TABLE wp_sonali_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        (id,brcode,brname,dist);
        ";
        $query = $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

**Error**

```
Output: 'Failed to move uploaded file.'
```

Comment: why not use `LOAD DATA INFILE ` ?

Comment: @splash58 can you please show me an example?

Comment: i've written an example as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "$_FILES['upload_csv']['tmp_name']"
INTO TABLE wp_sonali_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
("id", "brname", "brcode", "dist")
```

Comment: can you please modify my code with your example. Thanks !

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know wp db library. But i think it has method like query($string)

Comment: no offence @Firefog but if you don't understand his code, you should be reading up on SQL queries and learning what you need to pass through the values and work out which of your values fit in which parts of the SQL query statement

Comment: I have update my question with this method but `Failed to move uploaded file.` error output

Comment: I hope it's not due to the query :)